# Can Mandrill send bounced mail information to sender email

Tags: php, email, laravel, mandrill

I'm building a service for a company. The users of the service will send survey links to a list of email addresses. I'm going to use Mandrill as an email engine for this. The service is built using Laravel.

The users will feed a list of email addresses to the service that will generate emails (unique for every email address) and send them through the Mandrill API.

BUT, of course there will be errors made by the users. They will feed some bad email addresses in and emails will bounce. I need to find of way of notifying the users of the service that some emails have bounced.

**Is there a way to get Mandrill to send a list of bounced emails to the sender or reply address?**

Me as a developer has the Mandrill account of course, but I'm not interested in the bounce information - that has to go to the users of the system. So they can take action and correct the errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I see from Mandrill API that it is possible to get the status of sent e-mails with call `/exports/activity.json` as described in https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/exports.JSON.html#method-activity

If you get any bounced e-mails from there then you can manually send the corresponding messages to the users who you want to.